# Deploying spring-boot application to WildFly 8 causes container logs to be redirected

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, logback, wildfly-8

I'm trying to deploy a spring-boot application using logback to an existing WildFly 8 container, but as soon as the application has deployed all the container logs stop being written to `server.log` and end up being captured by the application logs.

The symptoms are similar to those described in [WildFly not logging after deploying app with Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914684). If I deploy an application which manually contains logback/slf4j dependencies, the application behaves as I'd expect (application logs go to application logfile, container logs go to server.log), so I'm assuming it's something to do with spring-boot? Can I configure this such that the container logging continues to be handled by Wildfly?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>logger-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="path_base" value="d:/test-logger/" />
    <property name="pattern"
        value="%date{ISO8601} %level %class{30} %thread %msg %mdc %ex{full} %n" />

    <!-- Simple File Appender -->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${path_base}test-logger.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${path_base}/archive/%d{yyyy-MM,aux}/test-logger.log.%d.%i.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %level %class{30} %thread %msg %mdc %ex{full} %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

**jboss-deployment.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>        
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**Spring boot initializer**

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(BootApp.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder if you have solved this issue by another way than excluding 'jul-to-slf4j'

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I deployed spring-boot application to websphere. After application prints banner all the log messages from websphere are logged into application log.

The problem occurred because spring-boot adds as one of its dependencies **jul-to-slf4j.jar** . This jar implements classes java.util.logging.* and websphere is also using java.util.logging hence by excluding jul-to-slf4j.jar from spring boot I was able to direct all websphere messages to container log and the application logs were written to application log.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:
Running Spring-boot 1.5.8 on Wildfly 9.0.2Final

I had to exclude the following before the logging was handled by the container:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` has `spring-boot-starter-logging` which had the dependencies i excluded.